# Сезон шляп — 2017: только лучшие шляпы!

Tags: поддержка, новости

<sub>Свободный перевод публикации из блога [Winter Bash 2017: Greatest <strike>Hits</strike> Hats!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/12/12/winter-bash-2017-greatest-hits-hats/)</sub>

---

С каждым градусом ниже нуля в северном полушарии мы приближаемся к Новому году. На Stack Overflow и других сайтах сети Stack Exchange ушки тысяч участников и участниц начинают подмерзать. А это значит, что настала пора согреть их … с помощью шляп!

[image]

В этот раз только избранное: в честь 6-й годовщины Сезона шляп<sup>1</sup> некоторые из самых полюбившихся шляп прошлых лет выступят на бис. Мы постарались настроить шляпы так, чтобы обеспечить максимальное веселье! (Ну а если вы соскучитесь, то всегда сможете отправиться на поиск новых шляп, ожидающих когда же их разыщут!)

[image]

Готовьтесь к зрелищным развлечениям и хорошему настроению!

Примите участие в соревнованиях на сайтах-участниках, чтобы получить шляпу и красоваться в ней везде, где отображается изображение из вашей учетной записи. Как только вы получаете новую шляпу, вы можете выбрать ее среди заработанных шляп в вашем профиле на любом из сайтов сети. Для этого просто нажмите на значок-шапку в разделе знаков для вызова меню выбора шляп.

[image]

Нажав на это изображение, вы увидите специальное меню.

[image]

При выборе шляпы вы можете изменить ее размер или расположение на изображении профиля, чтобы она точно подошла именно вам.

[image]

Сезон шляп — это уникальная возможность раз в год расслабиться и немного повеселиться всем вместе на Stack Overflow и других сайтах сети Stack Exchange. 
Но даже в сезон, когда мы прячем наши прически, надевая шляпы, мы крайне уважительно относимся к коллегам, которые предпочитают, чтобы их опыт на Stack Overflow и Stack Exchange был как можно более профессиональным: вы можете отказаться от участия в Сезоне шляп, выбрав «Я ненавижу шляпы» из меню «Снежинки» в верхней панели сайта.

Что касается всех остальных: с сегодняшнего дня (13 декабря 2017 года) и до 2 января 2018 года мы постараемся открыть все шляпы! Как обычно, по завершению сезона шляпы отправляются в дальний чулан, чтобы их больше никто никогда не надел ... если только лучшие шляпы не появятся снова через <strike>5</strike> 6 лет! Вот так!

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Забавный факт: авторы Сезона шляп хотели отпраздновать лучшими шляпами пятую годовщину, но, как оказалось после подсчета, это уже шестой зимний праздник. Получается, авторы Сезона шляп, как и все мы, подвержены ошибке неучтённой единицы.</sub>